# BeagleBone Black&Green Serial Connection Through 4-pin Cables

Tags: serial-port, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I have recently started playing around with the `BeagleBone` Computers and currently am trying to establish a serial connection between `BeagleBone Black` and `BeagleBone Green` with two 4-pin cables.

I would like to be able to connect to the `BeagleBone Green` using my `BeagleBone Black` that I will access through local network and `PuTTy` on my laptop. I am mainly in need of help on how to configure the hardware (the serial connection wiring between the two devices). It is also to my understanding that two 4-pin cables must be used; one to receive data from BBB and send data to `BBB`.

I have searched google and many other forums for anything similar but have not been successful.

Any input/advice would be very much appreciated :)

[BeagleBone Black & Green & 4-Pin Wires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Sj0.jpg)

[BeagleBone Green with 4-pin Wires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIEoZ.jpg)

Comment: *"4-pin Wires"* -- Pins are associated with connectors, not wires.  The number of pins on a connector is not a reliable indicator of the actual number of wires/conductors used by an interface.  You're using *"serial connection"* indiscriminately.  The BB Green seems to have one 4-pin port for a 3-wire (RxD, TxD, Gnd) TTL Serial (UART) interface plus power (for a TTL-to-RS232 converter).  The other 4-pin port looks like I2C or TWI (SCL, SDA and Gnd) plus a power pin; such an interface is never called *"serial"* by those who recognize it.  These interfaces are not the same and not compatible.

Comment: @sawdust If I wanted to connect BB Green with BB Black using serial connection, how would you suggest I go about it? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: On the BBB you'll have to configure a UART to use its pins by editing the Device Tree.  That should enable a RxD pin (which connects to the BBG TxD) and a TxD pin (connect to BBG RxD).  Pick any Gnd pin on the BBB to connect to the BBG Gnd.  Do not connect or use the 3.3V pin of the BBG serial port.  These logic connections should be made while both boards are not powered.  You then have to map the UARTi name to the Linux **/dev/ttyOj** name on each board.  Execute **picocom** terminal emulator program on each board to test.